# Why do I get the error object reference not set to instance of an ojbect while adding an object to a list in c# wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a C# WPF application with a form in it.  The form is supposed to take two values(firstName and lastName) and then use the Instructor class to add it to my listview element. On the line `instList.Add(new Instructor...` I am getting the error `object reference not set to instance of an object`.  Why does this happen?

This is my mainwindow.xaml.cs:

```
namespace AssignmentTwoPartTwo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public List<Instructor> instList;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<Instructor> instList = new List<Instructor> { };
            lvInstructorList.ItemsSource = instList;
        }

        private void btnCreateInstructor_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            spCreateInstructor.Visibility = (spCreateInstructor.Visibility == Visibility.Hidden) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
        }

        private void btnInstructorSubmit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            instList.Add(new Instructor() { firstName = txtInstructorFirstName.Text, lastName = txtInstructorLastName.Text });
            lvInstructorList.ItemsSource = instList;
        }
    }
}
```

This is Instructor.cs

```
namespace AssignmentTwoPartTwo
{
    public class Instructor
    {
        public string firstName { set; get; }
        public string lastName { set; get; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging? At which statement does it show that error?

Answer (score 0):

Pays to use a debugger here, you have 3 things that could cause it

```
instList.Add
txtInstructorFirstName.Text
txtInstructorLastName.Text
```

I'd say the top one is least likely.

Comment: So how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You are redeclaring the `instList` in the constructor, which shadows your instance variable. If you change your constructor to this, it should work:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    instList = new List<Instructor> { };
    lvInstructorList.ItemsSource = instList;
}
```

Comment: Good catch... buts its still a duplicate

Comment: Ok... but you have to admit that the linked post is very verbose for his case ;-).

Comment: Hopefully verbose enough he won't have to ask questions like this in the future :) In fact, this case is listed under "Bad Naming Conventions"